# How to check if image object is the same as one from resource?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

So I'm trying to create a simple program that just change the picture in a picture box when it's clicked. I'm using just two pictures at the moment so my code for the picture box click event function
looks like that:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (pictureBox1.Image == Labirint.Properties.Resources.first)
            pictureBox1.Image = Labirint.Properties.Resources.reitmi;
       else if (pictureBox1.Image == Labirint.Properties.Resources.reitmi)
            pictureBox1.Image = Labirint.Properties.Resources.first;
    }
```

For some reason the if statement it's not working and the picture don't change.
What should I do?

---

Note: original code contained bug with second `if` undoing effect of first if condition *would* work with fix suggested by [Cyral's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27749566/477420), but adding `else` did not fix the issue - stepping through the code with `else` still shows no matches for either image.

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == Labirint.Properties.Resources.first)
    pictureBox1.Image = Labirint.Properties.Resources.reitmi;
if (pictureBox1.Image == Labirint.Properties.Resources.reitmi) // was missing else
    pictureBox1.Image = Labirint.Properties.Resources.first;
```

Comment: The second if is always evaluated ; so it will undo what the first if statement did. It should be moved to an else clause. Perhaps there is a refresh function to be called as well.

Comment: I've significantly updated the question - please check if this matches your intentions. Note that I tried to match question to Hans Passant's answer as it contains actual explanation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
     if (pictureBox1.Image == Labirint.Properties.Resources.first)
```

There's a trap here that not enough .NET programmers are aware of.  Responsible for a *lot* of programs that run with bloated memory footprints.  Using the Labirint.Properties.Resources.xxxx property creates a **new** image object, it will never match any other image.  You need to use the property only once, store the images in a field of your class.  Roughly:

```
    private Image first;
    private Image reitmi;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        first = Labirint.Properties.Resources.first;
        reitmi = Labirint.Properties.Resources.reitmi;
        pictureBox1.Image = first;
    }
```

And now you can compare them:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (pictureBox1.Image == first) pictureBox1.Image = reitmi;
        else pictureBox1.Image = first;
    }
```

And to avoid the memory bloat:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
       first.Dispose();
       reitmi.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer about images from resources. I've tried to update question so it matches your answer - see if question can be improved more to make it into easier to find.

Comment: The Same goes for VB , but the comparison is : If pictureBox1.Image IS first Then ...

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `else if`, because if the image is `first`, you set it to `reitmi`, then you check if it is `reitmi`, which it now is, and change it back to `first`. This ends up not appearing to change at all.

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == Labirint.Properties.Resources.first)
    pictureBox1.Image = Labirint.Properties.Resources.reitmi;
else if (pictureBox1.Image == Labirint.Properties.Resources.reitmi)
    pictureBox1.Image = Labirint.Properties.Resources.first;
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't really help me it appears that it's not
entering into the if statement. If I just type
"pictureBox1.Image = Labirint.Properties.Resources.first;"

it will change the image in the box ("reitmi" is the initial picture), but if I add an if statement (even if single if) it is not working

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `pictureBox1.Image =` lines and see if they are hit.

Comment: No, they are not, the "pictureBox1.Image" value it's "System.Drawing.Image", according to the debugger, why it is not reitmi of first?

Comment: That is not the value, that is the *type*. Can you try with your old code to see if it equals either of them?

Comment: It's the same thing on the both columns value and type - "System.Drawing.Image"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can be a bit large, but works just fine with me, try it:

This is the requeriment:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;
```

And here is the code to compare:

```
        // Your Images
        Image img1 = pictureBox1.Image;
        Image img2 = pictureBox2.Image;

        // Now set as bitmap
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(img1);
        Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(img2);

        // here will be stored the bitmap data
        byte[] byt1 = null;
        byte[] byt2 = null;

        // Get data of bmp1
        var bitmapData = bmp1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);
        var length = bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height;
        //
        byt1 = new byte[length];
        //
        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, byt1, 0, length);
        bmp1.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        // Get data of bmp2
        var bitmapData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
        var length2 = bitmapData2.Stride * bitmapData2.Height;
        //
        byt2 = new byte[length2];
        //
        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData2.Scan0, byt2, 0, length2);
        bmp2.UnlockBits(bitmapData2);

        // And now compares these arrays
        if (StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(byt1, byt2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Is Equal");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Isn`t equal");
        }
```

this code compares each byte image to generate the result. may have other easier ways.

Comment: I sincerely doubt he needs a byte-comparison of the images. The way he is doing his assignment and checking, a simple reference compare will suffice.

Comment: yep, I too guess unnecessary, I always used this way but it is a bit slow too

Comment: I imagine it would be *very* slow for large images