# I can't get my IF statement to fire with Label.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.image1

Tags: c#, .net, image, if-statement, label

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
label1_Click(object sender, eventargs e){
       int number = 1;
       string labelName = "label" + number;
       Control area = this.Controls.Find(labelName, true)[0];
       if (area.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.image1){
            area.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.image2;
            ...
       }
       else {
             area.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.image3;
       }
}
```

I can't get my If statement to fire (It passes straight over it without saying there is an error in the code when trying to compare in my if statement). What is the best way to detect a label's background image? It's for a small game which requires a lot of image changes. I am flexible if Labels are a horrible way to do this but that's just how I started. The main goal is to dynamically detect a background image and change it to a different image depending on what the original image is and where the user clicks.

Comment: "I can't get my If statement to fire. " as in "I get exception on `.Find` line" OR "it runs `else` branch when I expect the first branch to be hit"?

Comment: It doesn't fire as in it passes straight over it.

Comment: I have no idea what (if anything) could be causing code to skip *both* branches of `if` statement... I'd recommend to rebuild code and carefully look at values while debugging - there is a good chance you'll spot the problem.

Comment: The best way to "detect a label's background image" is to not have to in the first place. Instead, maintain some state variable that tells you which image you're currently using (perhaps an array or dictionary of values, if you have to track for multiple objects). The only way your `if` statement could possible get skipped is if an exception were thrown (which you might not notice, because the Winforms event loop catches and absorbs exceptions). If you need specific help, you need to post [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I posted [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27750738/17034) to this question 5 hours before you asked it :)