# Gif animation is stopping on KeyPress event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gif

I'm developing a small Super Mario game in Visual Studio. I took 2 pictures of which the first one is Mario standing (png, not moving) and the second one is Mario running (gif, 3 frames). The problem is that, when I keep pressing on the "Right" button, the 3 frames inside the gif are processed only once then stop moving.

```
Private Sub Level1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
  Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.Right
      picBoxMario.Image = My.Resources.mario_running_right
  End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Level1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
  picBoxMario.Image = My.Resources.mario_standing_2
End Sub
```

Comment: A key will repeat when you hold it down, typically firing about two times per second.  Your code then *replaces* the image over and over again, ruining the animation effect.  Also a good way to crash your program, you need a Dispose() call to get these images destroyed again.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749541/how-to-check-if-image-object-is-the-same-as-one-from-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a Boolean check. So, if Mario is already running, you don't make it run again :).
Otherwise, your `PictureBox` will keep on showing the first frame only, because you keep feeding it the same animation over and over.

(I assume `Level1` is a `Form` and `KeyPreview = True`)

As Hans Passant noted in the comments, it's (more than) a good idea to assign those `Image` Resources to class objects that you can then `.Dispose()` when not needed anymore.

UPDATE: Based on the comments, an equality comparison using the class object, allows to further simplify the animation status check.

```
Private MarioRunning As Image = My.Resources.mario_running_right
Private MarioStanding As Image = My.Resources.mario_standing_2

Private Sub Level1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    picBoxMario.Image = MarioStanding
End Sub

Private Sub Level1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            If picBoxMario.Image.Equals(MarioRunning) Then Return
            picBoxMario.Image = MarioRunning
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Level1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    picBoxMario.Image = MarioStanding
End Sub
```

You could use the `FormClosing()` or `FormClosed()` events of your `Form` to dispose of the Images.

```
Private Sub Level1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    If MarioRunning IsNot Nothing Then MarioRunning.Dispose()
    If MarioStanding IsNot Nothing Then MarioStanding.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Somewhat notable that if he handles the images right then he doesn't need the boolean anymore.  A simple comparison on the Image property is then good enough.

Comment: Lots of programmers would wish that it would compare image content.  But no, that is rocket science.  It takes just a single cpu cycle, as much as the Boolean test.