How to make this code swap between background images on a button (A level minesweeper-based project)
If buttonClicked.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.bombsearchplain Then
    buttonClicked.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.bombsearchflag
    If buttonArray(currentX, currentY) = 1 Then
        correctFlags += 1
    End If
ElseIf buttonClicked.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.bombsearchflag Then
    buttonClicked.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.bombsearchplain
    If buttonArray(currentX, currentY) = 1 Then
        correctFlags -= 1
    End If
End If

When I click a button it just simply doesn't swap to the other background image when I want it to, is it because it does both the conditions inside 1 click?

Should swap between this and a flagging image, but it just stays as this whenever I click it.
Ignore the correct flags parts

What happens when you step through the code?

Also: Is is probably the wrong operator for those tests.

Images don't have equality comparisons unless you inspect every pixel.  Keep track of the button state in your matrix buttonArray(currentX, currentY) and test there.

@JoelCoehoorn why doesn't Is work here? I'm testing on my own, and it is fine for some cases checking reference equality with images, but not others. By others, I mean like in this case.

I'm not saying this is right. OP already knows how to solve this issue as evidenced by buttonArray - just use an object like this to hold the state, instead of checking images themselves. But I don't understand why these references aren't equal

@djv My.Resources is a Factory. It returns a new object each time you ask for one

@Jimi thank you, I just got there :) . Holding a private reference to those images and using that reference to set the BackgroundImages works.

@Jimi if you added that as an answer, I'd vote for it.

@jimi me too. If you haven't answered by tomorrow, I am going to :P

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32813850/14171304 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/27750738/14171304. Joy killer -->

@djv If you guys think that comment constitutes an answer (I don't, that's not the way to handle this kind of grid anyway, Bitmaps or not), then it's a duplicate of a number of other questions. For example, just considering VB.NET, I wrote about it here and here. dr.null also posted others. This is quite an outstanding feature of the ResourceManager (though I agree that the official docs are not exactly clear about it)

@djv ... It could interesting if someone asked for it directly, then talking about the functionality of the UnmanagedMemoryStream and the UnmanagedMemoryStreamWrapper that manage the objects as streams when ResourceManager.GetObject() is called, then return the stream as a new object of the requested type, would make sense. Here, probably not that much

Managed to fix it had to use a public array that would be populated depending on where there is a flag

Try to modify your Code such that:
If buttonClicked.BackgroundImage.Tag Is My.Resources.bombsearchplain.Tag Then
    buttonClicked.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.bombsearchflag
    If buttonArray(currentX, currentY) = 1 Then
        correctFlags += 1
    End If
ElseIf buttonClicked.BackgroundImage.Tag Is My.Resources.bombsearchflag.Tag Then
    buttonClicked.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.bombsearchplain
    If buttonArray(currentX, currentY) = 1 Then
        correctFlags -= 1
    End If
End If

with the flag tags as:
My.Resources.bombsearchplain.Tag = "plain"
My.Resources.bombsearchflag.Tag = "flag"

